# How to analyze two seemingly equivalent programs with different behavior in coq?

Tags: compiler-construction, coq, theorem-proving

I'm working through the compiler correctness proof in programming language foundations, and was scratching my head for hours before caving in and applying this solution I found on line (https://github.com/haklabbeograd/software-foundations-coq-workshop/blob/master/Imp.v).  I tried to adapt my function (the first s_execute), but it still won't work in order to prove the lemma below (only the latter implementation works).  Additionally, I can only get the online solution to work when I run it in his file, not mine (all the definitions are the same except for instr vs sinstr and variables are defined slightly differently).
Why is this (specically, why does the unification error only occur in the former solution)?  Additionally, in the book it says:

Remember that the specification left unspecified what to do when encountering an [SPlus], [SMinus], or [SMult] instruction if the stack contains less than tw elements.  (In order to make your correctness proof easier you might find it helpful to go back and change your implementation!)

Which definition does the author intend us to change in order to get this correct?

```
Fixpoint s_execute (st : state) (stack : list nat)
                   (prog : list instr)
  : list nat :=
  match prog with
  | [] => stack
  | x :: xs => match x, stack with
                 | (SPush n), ys => s_execute st (n :: ys) xs
                 | (SLoad x), ys => s_execute st ((st x) :: ys) xs
                 | SPlus, y1 :: y2 :: ys => s_execute st ((y1 + y2) :: ys) xs
                 | SMinus, y1 :: y2 :: ys => s_execute st ((y2 - y1) :: ys) xs
                 | SMult, y1 :: y2 :: ys => s_execute st ((y2 * y1) :: ys) xs
                                                      | _, _ => stack
               end
  end.
```

```
Fixpoint s_execute (st : state) (stack : list nat)
                   (prog : list instr)
                 : list nat :=
let newstack :=
  match prog with
    | [] => stack
    | (SPush n)::_ => n::stack
    | (SLoad id)::_ => (st id)::stack
    | SPlus::_  => match stack with
                        | n::(m::rest) => (m+n)::rest
                        | _ => stack
                      end
    | SMinus::_  => match stack with
                         | n::m::rest => (m-n)::rest
                         | _ => stack
                       end
    | SMult::_  => match stack with
                        | n::m::rest => (m*n)::rest
                        | _ => stack
                      end
  end in
  match prog with
    | [] => stack
    | instr::rest => s_execute st newstack rest
  end.
```

The below lemma only works with the second implementation, even though both match the examples given s_execute(1|2).

```
Lemma s_execute_app : forall st p1 p2 stack,
  s_execute st stack (p1 ++ p2) = s_execute st (s_execute st stack p1) p2.
  intros st p1.
  induction p1.
  intros; reflexivity.
  intros.
  apply IHp1.
Qed.
```

Comment: I struggled for a couple of hours with proving the Lemma. The part which had me stuck was failing to create an inductive hypothesis generalized in both p2 AND the stack. Note that in the author's proof of s_execute_app, the first line is "intros st p1", not "intros. generalize dependent p2".

Answer (score 0):

These two definitions of `s_execute` are not equivalent: when encountering an invalid instruction, the first one stops immediately (`_, _ => stack`) while the second one skips it but still evaluates the rest of the program (`s_execute ... rest`).

Because of that difference, the first version does not satisfy the `s_execute_app` lemma. However, that lemma is not part of the exercise, it's only an addition by the author of the solution you found, which may make the final proof easier but is not strictly required.

So that's the main reason why the proof doesn't go through: it can't.

However, the proof does get stuck a bit earlier than it could go, because of the differences in syntax: the first definition does more `match`es before exposing the recursive call to `s_execute`, whereas the second definition only does one `match` at the beginning, and hides the rest in a local definition `newstack`.

```
  let newstack := ... in
  match prog with                                   (* One match... *)
    | [] => stack
    | instr::rest => s_execute st newstack rest     (* ... and the recursive call is revealed *)
  end.
```

If you look at where you get stuck in the proof with your version of `s_execute`, the goal is a big pile of `match` which looks nothing like the induction hypothesis, and that's why the last `apply` doesn't go through. The common thing to try when there is a `match` in the goal is to `destruct` whatever is being matched. Two of the cases are easily dispatched with `apply IHp1`, so we can chain those tactics like this, to be left with the three arithmetic operations, where the induction hypothesis still doesn't apply.

```
destruct a eqn:Ea; try apply IHp1.
```

Again more `matches` in the goal.

```
destruct stack.
```

and now we get to an unsolvable goal:

```
--------------------------------------
[ ] = s_execute st [ ] p2
```

Try to understand why this is incorrect, and then by going back step-by-step, you can reconstruct a counterexample to the initial proposition.

> Which definition does the author intend us to change in order to get this correct?

Both definitions look correct (I haven't verified yours), but the second definition most likely leads to some more concise proofs for the reasons I explained above.

Comment: Thank you, @Li-yao Xia. Is there another 'more natural' lemma you would suggest using to prove the compiler correctness?

Comment: I'm not sure you need a special lemma for this. Struggling with the theorem to get an idea of the right way to generalize it for induction is the standard way to go about it.